# Ошибка с модулем random при запуске телеграмм бота на сервер

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, heroku

Пытаюсь запустить бота на сервер Heroku, но возникают трудности:
Бот должен начать работать после команды:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Но я получаю следующее сообщение:

```
»   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.2.
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (worker).
```

Ранее, в командной строке я прописывал:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

И получал ответ, что все хорошо кроме:

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for random
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: Создайте файл requirements.txt со всеми вашими библиотеками.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл `requirements.txt` рядом с вашим ботом и напишите в нем:

```
random2==1.0.1
```

Также создайте файл `Procfile` (**Без расширения**), и в нём напишите:

```
worker: python ИМЯ_ОСНОВНОГО_ФАЙЛА_БОТА
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Та же ошибка.